# windows unable to enable .net framework 3.5

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows

I am stuck in a situation where all the solution on internet and stack overflow is not helping me .
I want to enable .net framework 3.5 in my machine for this i followed these steps.

1. Downloaded it
2. installed it
3. Control Panel
4. Programs and features
5. Turn Windows features on and off
6. I enabled .net 3.5 from there
   It shows a message "**Windows need to restart your PC to finish installing the requested changes**"

I restarted my system , but it is still not enabled the SQL server installation is still showing an error for .net  framework 3.5.

Comment: any error messages while enabling it in windows feature ?

Comment: there is no error

Comment: So does the .net 3.5 enabled ?

Comment: no it does not after restarting the system , it is still not enabled

Comment: maybe this will help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/microsoft-net-framework-35-deployment-considerations